# Oracle-sql query

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, proc

I want to use single cursor to fetch single record or all records using where condition, e.g. : `student` is table and `sid` is an attribute.

I have two cursors,

`DECLARE S1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM Student;`

and

`Declare S2 Cursor for select * from Student where sid=11`

My query is on how to combine these two conditions to use only one cursor. I need this as I have two functions `m_viewStudent` and `m_viewallStudents`, for this I would like to use only one cursor to display the requested details from table.

so how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Why did this get closed as "off topic"? This question seems decidedly about programming and software development. If not, there's a LOT of SQL questions that need to be closed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * 
from student
where sid = 11 
or not exists (select 1 from student where sid = 11)
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60b16/1)

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to use the same cursor for different functions then you can do it like this:

```
create package p is

  procedure one_sid(in_sid number);
  procedure all_sid;

end p;
/

create package body p is

  cursor c(p_sid number) is
  select * 
    from student 
   where sid = p_sid or p_sid is null;

  procedure one_sid(in_sid number) is

  begin

   open c(in_sid);

   close c;

  end;

  procedure all_sid is

  begin

   open c(null);

   close c;

  end;

end p;
/
```

Comment: Let me explain , I have two functions m_viewStudent,m_viewallStudents for this i would like to use only one cursor to display the requested details from table so how can i achieve this ?

Comment: thank you and your first query solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can change the cursor to

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE sid like '%' || variable_from_function || '%';
```

This will ensure that when function `m_viewStudent` calls this, only the sid (value sent to this function variable_from_function) record is picked. When `m_viewallStudents` calls this, all records get picked as variable_from_function would be null.

Comment: Thank you @Orangecrush i got solution and editing my question too

Comment: @Venkatesh Glad to be of help. If it is working, upvote and mark the answer as accepted for further reference and to help other people with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your procedure variable is `$var`, try this:

```
Declare S2 Cursor for select * from Student 
    where sid=$var 
        or $var is null
```

And pass in a null when you want them all, or make the default value of the parameter null and pass in no parameter

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with a Cursor Variable, more commonly called a Ref Cursor.  This is basically a pointer to a result set.  The advantage of a Ref Cursor is that we can vary the select statement, like this:

```
create or replace package student_utils is

   --  a hard-types ref cursor
   type stud_cur is ref cursor return students%rowtype;
   function get_students 
      ( p_sid in students.sid%type  := null )
      return  stud_cur;
end;
```

Note that I have made a couple of presumptions about how you are intending to use the code.   Using a package allows us to define a hard-typed ref cursor, which means that it can only be used for queries which match the projection of the STUDENTS table.  (If you don't have an actual STUDENTS table you can use of of the views or define a Pl/SQL Record instead.)

```
create or replace package body student_utils is

   function get_students 
      ( p_sid in students.sid%type := null )
      return  stud_cur
   is
       return_value stud_cur;
   begin
       if p_sid is null
       then
           open return_value for 
                select * from m_viewallStudents;
       else
           open return_value for 
                select * from m_viewStudent
                where sid = p_sid;
       end if;  
       return return_value;
    end;
end;
```

These queries are hard-coded but we can also open Ref Cursors with dynamic SQL, which is a powerful technique.

Read the documentation to [find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#i7106)